# Rotate an image by 15 degrees increments?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, image-rotation

I'm faced with what seems to be a very daunting task. I need to rotate an image, within a PictureBox, in increments of 15 degrees. After quite some time spent searching the depths of the internet, I've not found anything to achieve this task. The closest thing I could come up with was a 90 degree flip using:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitializeBitmap()
End Sub

Dim bitmap1 As Bitmap

Private Sub InitializeBitmap()
    Try
        bitmap1 = CType(Bitmap.FromFile("G:\Documents\Dawson\Semster 3\Visual Basic I\Test\subs\subs\Wheel.bmp"), Bitmap)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap1
    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Check the path to the bitmap.")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If bitmap1 IsNot Nothing Then
        bitmap1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY)
        PictureBox1.Image = bitmap1
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm in need of code that will flip my image by 15 degree increments; nothing more, and nothing less.

Anyone willing to provide this code to me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [CodeProject article showing how to rotate an image in a PictureBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58815/C-Image-PictureBox-Rotations).

The basic approach requires using GDI and the [Graphics class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get the image, perform the rotation (via methods like [Graphics.RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)), then save the results as an image, and assign it to your `PictureBox` control.

Comment: The code at this link translated to VB very well. It gets my job done nicely. Thank you so much for the help!